# Export OSC Server on Runway

Tags: python, machine-learning

I’m having a problem with Runway exporting in OSC to TouchDesigner. I was working on this patch: http://github.com/BarakChamo/TD_PoseNet , inside **posenet_osc** I got this warning that got me stuck:

> Warning: Unable to join multicast group, address must be between
>   224.0.0.1 and 239.255.255.255. 239.255.0.1-239.255.0.255 is recommended. Error 3 (/project1/posenet_osc/osc)

It force me to **change** the **OSC Server Address** on **PoseNet** but it can’t be done, so I got stuck. Could someone help me?